# how to post multiple values via ajax $.post method to php script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have an image button below each image gallery. I want post the values of a,b,c,d,e,f,g to a php script once the image button clicked. if php script successfully inserted the a,b,c,d,e,f,g in to mysql i want to changed the image button so user knows data entered successfuly!

could any one show me how i can make such ajax post method with multiple values and how to change the image button if ajax post request was successfull? in my php script what should i add so ajax knows data was inserted successfully to mysql db ?

```
<html>

<head>

<script>
function postLike(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) {

//after sussceffuly insert to mysql i want to change image button to this  
    $('#like12').html(" <img class='lb-liked' onclick='deleteLike(&quot;" + b + "&quot;)' src='/liked.png' title='like' border='0' />");  


    }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="like12" style="float: left; padding: 10px 2px 2px;"> 
<img class="liker" onclick='postLike("http://somesite.com/12345.jpg","stacy","http://somesite.com/season_456565656.jpg","123456789","http://somesite.com/abddef/","98765432","cool season")' src="./like.png" border="0">
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of possible ways to post multiple values over HTTP, so it really depends.

```
// post as array
$.post(url, "val[]=" + a + "&val[]=" + b
// post as separate values
$.post(url, "val1=" + a + "&val2=" + b
// post as JSON string
$.post(url, "values=" + JSON.stringify([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

Comment: thanks for reply. could you show me the complete ajax request using post as separate values ?

Comment: @user1788736 I don't understand what you mean.  The second option uses separate values.

Comment: i just wanted the function that makes such post request and url of php script where it should be declared? and on success how i change my current button ?

Comment: It could be inside `postLike.`  `$.post(/* arguments */).done(function () { /* success function */ })`.  Read the jQuery documentation on `$.ajax`

Comment: if php doesnt enter data because of duplication how i can inform the ajax about it so it inform the user with alert ?

Comment: @user1788736 you can change what gets sent back by the php.  `if ($success) { echo "success"; } else { echo "failed because of duplicate"; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
$.post(url,{val1: a, val2: b},function(data){
// success
alert("yay");
}
}
}
</script>
<div id="button" style="background-color:#000;width:30px;height:30px;"></div>
```